How to define an equitable success event in quantum-walk-based multiple-targets search algorithm?
In quantum search algorithms (on a 2D grid or other setting), when there are multiple targets, a "successful search" event is often defined in following:
$$P_{success}=\max_{t\in [0,T]} \sum_i^{\text{all targets}} p_i(t)= \sum_i^{\text{all targets}} p_i(t_{success}).$$
But doesn’t this seem a bit strange? I must already know the exact positions of the targets in advance to calculate this sum and identify the position with the highest probability, which would define the success of the search. It feels like I have some sort of "god's eye view".  Is there a more equitable definition for this? Thanks.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

What do you mean by 'equitable' here?

Not sure I understand the question properly, but measuring the site where the walker is will, with probability P_success, return a valid target state. Thus, if P_success is large enough, and one can check that one found a target, one will have a large enough probability to find a target state when measuring.

@KyleKanos hi, we cannot assume that we already know the exact positions of all the targets in advance.

@NorbertSchuch hi, based on your comment, does this mean that $P_{\text{success}} $ is well-defined and reliable? Is it possible that the probability of one particular target is significantly higher, while the probabilities at the other targets are relatively moderate, and the total probability is large enough when these two parts are combined?

@yuzhe I don't see how your response answers the question I asked. Equitable usually means "to be dealt fairly with" (and is usually used in context of some socioeconomic metric or legal sense), which doesn't seem to apply here.

@KyleKanos Hi, how about I put it another way: replacing "equitable" with "same prior information". It seems that when I write down the above equation, it's as if I already know some prior information about targets in advance. I'm trying to construct a search that doesn't rely on so—one that's completely fair, where no prior information about the targets or non-targets is given in advance.
